# Tombstone misplaced with `multline*` and `\qedhere`

Tags: amsthm, multline

It looks like the end-of-proof symbol is misaligned if `multline*` and `\qedhere` are used. Or am I just using them wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
 Only words here.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{equation*}
  A=form(u)la. \qedhere
 \end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{multline*}
  A=form(u)la.\\ with/many*lines \qedhere
 \end{multline*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: this is definitely a known issue, but you have turned up a previously unknown problem as well -- with `equation*` a spurious warning is issued.  that has been added to our list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue; the log file for your example contains the following.

> Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly
>   here on input line 15.

I'm not aware of a fix, but there are others here who know much more about `ams` packages than I do. A workaround is

```
\tag*{$\qed$}
```

in place of `\qedhere`.

Comment: I checked, and I get that warning once for line 9 (where the `\qedhere` inside the `equation*` is) and twice for line 15 (where the one inside `multline*` is). Strange. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out; I use kile, and it did not display the warning for some reason.

Comment: this workaround will do the right thing only when equation numbers are positioned on the right.  also, it's necessary to suppress the non-"here" box with `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}`; since a proof is a local group, this definition will not persist after `\end{proof}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Another workaround is to "guess" the correct shift and do `\let\myqedsymbol\qedsymbol \def\qedsymbol{\myqedsymbol\hspace*{-10pt}} \qedhere` inside `minipage*`. It's a dirty solution, but it works; one just have to make sure that the output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436170/34905) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130655), `amsthm` should be loaded *after* `amsmath. I just tried by replacing

```
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
```

by

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! On my machine, changing the order of the two packages results in the last tombstone being a little too far on the *left*, rather than on the *right*. So this change does something, but it does not fix the issue.