# How to put the QED symbol of a proof at the right place inside align?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, align

When a proof ends with a formula in `equation` or `equation*` environment, putting `\qedhere` after the equation would cause the QED symbol to appear in the right place. I.e. at the end of the line in which the equation appears. For example:

```
\begin{equation}
  x = y+z \qedhere
\end{equation}
```

However, I cannot get the same result when the formula is inside an `align`/`align*` environment using the same method:

```
\begin{align}
  x &= a+b \\
    &= y+z \qedhere
\end{align}
```

The square appears just after (y+z) and is not shifted to the right boundary of the page.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Example to Show QED is Misplaced}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  This proof is typeset correctly:
  \begin{equation*}
    x = y + z \qedhere
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
  But this one not!
  \begin{align*}
    x & = u + v \\
    & = y + z \qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the proof environment of the acm packages?

Comment: `ntheorem` might also be worth a look

Comment: It appears at the right margin in my experiment (but it has the side effect of removing the equation number). Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I added a MWE to the end of my question. I am sorry, I don't know how can I upload the MWE file directly.

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi The `cmex10` option to `amsmath` may be needed only with very old TeX installations; don't use it unless you get a `Math formula deleted` error. In this case, first try updating your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change the order, this works just fine, `amsthm` *after* `amsmath`, otherwise it might be a bit hard for it to hook into `align*`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Example to Show QED is Misplaced}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This proof is typeset correctly:
\begin{equation*}
x = y + z \qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
But this one not!
\begin{align*}
x & = u + v \\
& = y + z \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with the package order `amsthm` before `amsmath`, a warning is issued: `Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly here on input line ...`. it's also documented in the first section of `amsthdoc` that "`amsthm` must be loaded *after* `amsmath`, not before."

Comment: Another caveat, be sure to have all the `&` in the last line. If the preceding lines contained for example there `&` don't forget to use all of them on the last line too.

Comment: When I do this, my QED symbol overlaps on top of the text inside the align* environment. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamer please post a question of your own including a suitable minimal example.

Answer (score 15):

Section 5 of the [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package documentation contains the following.

> When used with the `amsmath` package, version 2 or later, `\qedhere` will
>   position the QED symbol flush right; with earlier versions, the symbol
>   will be spaced a quad away from the end of the text or display. If
>   `\qedhere` produces an error message in an equation, try using
>   `\mbox{\qedhere}` instead.

However, when I tried this with your example I got a QED symbol one quad away from the end of the display, despite the fact that my distribution contains amsmath version 2.13. However, using

```
\tag*{\qedhere}
```

instead solved the problem.

Comment: see the second paragraph of section "1 introduction" of `amsthdoc`.  (i had to check, because if it didn't already say that the loading order is important, i would have to add it to the list of bugs.  glad i don't have to.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Consider the following code: 
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    &x && =1 \\
    &y && =2 
    \qedhere
  \end{alignat*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}`
amsmath is loaded before amsthm, yet latex issues a warning. The warning is not issued if align is used instead of alignat (but the result is ugly). Am I misusing alignat or is there an issue here?

Comment: @brad -- `alignat*` should work the same as `align*`.  I'm not able to test this right now, but surely this deserves its own question, so please post one.  (That will also make ie easier to copy and paste the example code.  I'm not at all sure why the first `{2}` is in braces, but that shouldn't make any difference.)  Please also show the warning that is issued.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : I did, cfr. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691610/problem-using-qedhere-inside-alignat). Thank you.