# Need \qedhere to be flush with the right margin in cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

How can I do this?

When I put `\qedhere` in cases environment, the square is between the margins somewhere.  It is not where the square appears in the usual proof environment, at the right margin.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{ut}{Theorem}

\begin{document}



\begin{proof}

$$
X(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
x(n),\\
x(n-1)\\
x(n-1)\qedhere
\end{cases}
$$
\end{proof}

\begin{ut}The sky is blue.\end{ut}

\begin{proof}Duh.\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the QED symbol of a proof at the right place inside align?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-to-put-the-qed-symbol-of-a-proof-at-the-right-place-inside-align)

Comment: @MaartenDhondt but I put amsthm after amsmath like it suggested...

Comment: @MaartenDhondt I don't think so. There's no `align` here and the problem is completely different.

Comment: It seems I was too quick in judging this as a duplicate. I'll retract my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abuse `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{ut}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\[
\begin{gathered}[b]
X(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
x(n),\\
x(n-1)\\
x(n-1)
\end{cases}
\\
\end{gathered}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{ut}The sky is blue.\end{ut}

\begin{proof}Duh.\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

In my opinion this is not the right place, as the baseline should be determined by *X*(*m,n*).

[image]

Comment: thanks. by the way, what's the difference between using \ [  and $$ ?

Comment: @ForeverMozart See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 3):

You could place the `\qedhere` outside the `cases` and raise the box.  Or, see **follow up** to avoid having to recalculate the raise amount for each different `cases` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{ut}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}

\[
\raisebox{1.2\baselineskip}{$\displaystyle
X(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
x(n),\\
x(n-1)\\
x(n-1)
\end{cases}$}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{ut}The sky is blue.\end{ut}

\begin{proof}Duh.\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP:**

If you didn't want to have to calculate the shift each time, you could use the `stackengine` package, with `\abovebaseline[-\dp\strutbox]{...}` in lieu of the `\raisebox{shift length}{...}`.

Comment: oh that looks right.  by the way, how did you know to use value 1.2?

Comment: @ForeverMozart Trial and error, knowing it to be approximately `1\baselineskip`.  See my edited answer to see how to avoid having to calculate the value for each different `cases`.

Answer (score 2):

Following @egreg's suggestion as to the placement of the `qed symbol`, there's almost nothing to do: just replace `$$ … $$` with `\[ … \]`. One more illuùminating example of why the latter is preferable:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{ut}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[Proof 1]

  \[
    X(m,n)=
    \begin{cases}
      x(n), \\ x(n-1)\\ x(n-1)
    \end{cases}
    \qedhere
  \]
\end{proof}
\vskip4ex

\begin{proof}[Proof 2]

  $$
  X(m,n)=
  \begin{cases}
    x(n), \\ x(n-1) \\ x(n-1)
  \end{cases}
  \qedhere
  $$

  \begin{ut}The sky is blue.\end{ut}

  \begin{proof}Duh.\end{proof}

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]