# Insert punctuation into a prooftree

Tags: bussproofs

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{proof}
 \usepackage{bussproofs}


\begin{document}

This is for test

\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\vdash  \{A \land b \}c\{A\}$}
\UnaryInfC{$\vdash \{A\} \textrm{ while } b \textrm{ do } c \{A \land
\lnot b\}$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}

This is for test

\end{document}
```

[image]
This codes working fine, but I need to insert a period at the end of display proof, please advise how to do it?

Comment: google for: latex qed and results are e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34014/qed-for-theorems-without-proofs https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-to-put-the-qed-symbol-of-a-proof-at-the-right-place-inside-align/130655 maybe they will give you some pointers

Comment: @albert Sorry, both the suggestions are related with how to place \qedsymbol by using amsthm.sty, but my requirement is different from these, anyway, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\DisplayProof`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\newenvironment{iproof}{}{\DisplayProof}

\begin{document}

This is for test
\[
\begin{iproof}
\AxiomC{$\vdash  \{A \land b \}c\{A\}$}
\UnaryInfC{$\vdash \{A\} \textrm{ while } b \textrm{ do } c \{A \land
\lnot b\}$}
\end{iproof}\,.
\]
This is for test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as usual you are really great...it works fine....