# Problem using \qedhere inside alignat

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, alignat, qed

As suggested by Barbara Beeton [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-to-put-the-qed-symbol-of-a-proof-at-the-right-place-inside-align/130654?noredirect=1#comment1716082_130654), I am posting this as a new question.

When a proof ends in a displayed formula, to have the QED symbol in the correct place you have to use `\qedhere` inside the formula.

The problem is that if the formula is given by means of the `alignat*` environment, then LaTeX issues a (harmless) warning when compiling.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  &x && =1 \\
  &y && =2 
  \qedhere
 \end{alignat*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{align*}
  x & =1 \\
  y & =2 
  \qedhere
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Please note that `amsmath` is called before `amsthm`, as specified in `amsthdoc`

When compiling, I get the (double) warning

```
Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly here on input line 10.

Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly here on input line 10.
```

The QED symbol is still there (albeit not flushed to the right).

If you use the environment `align*` instead of `alignat*`, on the other hand, everything works flawlessly.

As Barbara said, they should work the same, but it looks like they don't.

P.S.: A way to avoid the warning is to use `\tag*{\qedhere}` instead of `\qedhere`, which has also the side effect to flush the QED symbol to the right, restoring it to its intended position, but this looks more like a sort of workaround than the intended use of `\qedhere`.

Comment: I am doubtful that they "should work the same". Firstly, `amsthm.sty` explicitly defines handlers for `\qedhere` for the environments `equation`, `equation*`, `displaymath`, `split`, `align`, `align*`, `gather`, and `gather*`. Interestingly _none is defined for `alignat` or `alignat*`_. Secondly, if one just copy over verbatim the definition of the handler for `align*` and try to use it for `alignat*`, one gets an incorrect result. So I am not sure whether the omission is an oversight or something deliberate.

Comment: @WillieWong -- I don't remember any reason why `alignat*` would have been omitted from the applicable display structures.  I've confirmed that this does indeed happen, and I'm quite puzzled.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I spent the last 1.5 hours looking at `amsthm.sty` and `amsmath.sty` and I *think* I have a fix, though I don't have a full explanation why the current code should work (it seems rather hacky) for `align`. (Basically it tries to place the tag using the same mechanism for both `align` and `gather`, which is strange as normally in `amsmath.sty` the `align` type environments and `gather` type environments have distinct methods for placing tags.) Anyway, I posted an answer below, feel free to edit / correct.

Comment: @WillieWong -- I've called on David Carlisle for help, and turned the task for fixing this over to him and the AMS TeXnical support group.  Let's hope a real fix becomes public soon.  Thanks for your digging and analysis.

Answer (score 6):

The following solution should work with both documents with or without `leqno`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\qed@tag@alignat{%
    \global\tag@true \nonumber
    &\omit\setboxz@h {\strut@ \qedsymbol}%
    \iftagsleft@%
        \global\advance\tagshift@-\displaywidth%
    \fi%
    \tagsleft@false
    \place@tag
    \kern-\tabskip
    \ifst@rred \else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi \global\advance\row@\@ne \cr
  }

\def\alignat@qed{%
    \ifmeasuring@ \tag*{\qedsymbol}%
    \else \let\math@cr@@@\qed@tag@alignat
    \fi
  }
  \@xp\let\csname alignat*@qed\endcsname\alignat@qed
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  &x && =1 \\
  &y && =2 
  \qedhere
\end{alignat*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
 \begin{align*}
  x & =1 \\
  y & =2 
  \qedhere
 \end{align*}
 \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

**Explanation**

Most of the code is copied directly from what is in use for the `align` environment in `amsthm.sty`, the key difference is that we define a new `\qed@tag@alignat` macro.

In `amsthm.sty` a `\qed@tag` macro is defined, which works well for both `gather` and `align` environments; but the fact that it works with `align` is mostly a hack. A short and slightly inaccurate description of why the hack is needed is:

> Ideally we want something like `\tag*{\qedsymbol}` to work. If the world doesn't have `leqno` documents, then exactly the form above is okay. But if you have a left-numbered equation, then `\tag*{\qedsymbol}` would print it on the wrong side. So we have to do something more clever to shove the `\qedsymbol` all the way right even when `leqno` is involved.

Normally, the placement of the tag is computed differently between `gather` and `align` environments (they have their own `\place@tag@gather` and `\place@tag` macros). In `\qed@tag` a hack is (ab)used to allow `\place@tag@gather` to also work in the context of `align` environments; I haven't worked out fully the mechanism yet, but it has something to do with how `\llap` works in right-aligned columns and the spacing inserted between groups of columns in `align`. Whatever it is it **doesn't** work with `alignat`.

In the code above we try to solve the issue of `leqno` differently. Fundamentally the reason that `leqno` causes an issue for using `\place@tag` is because during typesetting, the position of the tag, determined by `\tagshift@`, is computed during the "measuring phase" of the typesetting of the equations (`amsmath` famously uses a two pass approach to set the equations). During this phase the code doesn't know that there will be a `\qedsymbol` that ought to be placed flush right. The difference (between whether `leqno` is in force or not) boils down to a length of `\displaywidth`. So in the code above, we call `\place@tag` (which is designed to work with `alignat`), but we correct for the missing `\displaywidth` if necessary. This allows for the correct placement both in the left- and right-numbered `alignat`s.

(This should, in principle, also work with `align`; but this will not work for `gather`. So potentially one may envision patching `amsthm.sty` so that the `\qedhere` invocation works using the above code for both `align` and `alignat`, but leaving the original code for `gather`.

Comment: looks good......

Comment: This looks promising! Your last remark makes sense to me: I can easily imagine that `align` and `alignat` share the same code as much as I can easily understand that `gather` needs  different code. Finally, I must say that I do not agree with `amsthdoc` when it says that `\qedhere` is inappropriate for use with displays numbered
on the right: IMO it is appropriate and should place the symbol just under the last tag. I obtain this simply adding a last empty line... ;)