# Multline and qedhere

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, multline

One of the proofs in my paper ends with a multi-line equation. Unfortunately, when I put the QED sign at the end via the \qedhere command, it does not end up at the end of the line like the other QED signs (it also throws a warning that \qedhere may not work correctly). The difference is not big, but it's kind of annoying. How to make it right?

EDIT: now I see that a similar question [has already been asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102079/40862), but that was five years ago (and the suggested workaround does not seem to work). Has nothing changed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        This is the first proof.
    \end{proof}

    \begin{proof}
        This is another proof.
        \begin{multline}
            6\cdot 9=\\
            42\qedhere
        \end{multline}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this is a known bug of `amsthm`.

Comment: @egreg: I see. Still, maybe one can work around it?

Comment: Strangely, your code doesn't have this problem on my system.

Comment: @Bernard: well, on my system the result is this: https://imgur.com/a/8AzSgYv

Comment: @tomasz -- i've taken the liberty of adding the image.

Comment: Oh!  see. I thought you meant the vertical alignment. I also have this shift. However, with `ntheorem` (and the `article` class), everything is fine – and I don't have to type `\qedhere`.

Comment: @Bernard: Interesting. Unfortunately, adding '\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm]{ntheorem}' to the preamble of my actual document (documentclass book) results in a boatload of errors.

Comment: Even without the `amsthm` option?

Comment: @Bernard: even without it.

Comment: There's probably some thing in your code that is incompatible with `ntheorem`, such as also loading `amsthm`. Can you compile the very code you posted (just modified to use ntheorem)?

Comment: @Bernard: I don't really know how to use ntheorem. The main issue seems to be that ntheorem does not know the proof environment, and it tries to redefine theoremstyle plain from amsthm (or vice versa).

Comment: If you load it with the `[amsmath, thmmarks, standard]` options it defines a `proof` environment (and lemma, theorem, definition &c.). If you don't like the details of the layout, it's easy to customise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this isn't ideal, but if you're willing to put up with the vertically centered
equation number and qed box, and the narrowed alignment of the display math,
it at least doesn't complain.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        This is the first proof.
    \end{proof}

    \begin{proof}
        This is another proof.
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{multlined}
            6\cdot 9=\\
            42
        \end{multlined}
        \qedhere
    \end{equation}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really care about the equation number (I don't really do numbered equations in the first place). The fact that the qed box is centered is a bit annoying, but better than having it horizontally misaligned. While indeed not perfect, this seems good enough. Thanks!