# Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command... in Documenta style

Tags: theorems, warnings, amsthm, article

I am trying to adjust my manuscript to Documenta style which can be found [here](https://ojs.elibm.org/index.php/dm/about/submissions) (`\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}`). Whenever I use the `\qedhere`-command at the end of an `equation`- or `equation*`-environment, I get the following warning:

> Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly here on inp ut line XY.

In the initial version of my manuscpript in the `amsart`-documentclass, there was no similar warning.

In the output, I cannot see that the `\qedhere`-command does not work correctly. However, I would like to get rid of the warning. How I can get rid of this warning?

I think you can reproduce the effect when you load the above style and use `\qedhere` in an `equation`- or `equation*`-environment. It is therefore not necessary to provide a MWE.

Many thanks for your help. I would like to work through other warnings (e.g. overfull boxes) but this maybe useless `amsthm`-warning prevents from doing so in `overleaf`. I do not understand in the first place why it suddenly comes up.

**Addendum.** I load the following packages, in case it is relevant.

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,verbatim,amsmath,color,fancyhdr,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\def\tequiv{\ensuremath\sdststile{}{}}

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,dvips]{geometry}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `amscd`. The results are not very good. Use `tikz-cd` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130655), `amsthm` should be loaded after `amsmath`. As described in a [comment on that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-to-put-the-qed-symbol-of-a-proof-at-the-right-place-inside-align/130655#comment294629_130655), this warning is produced when `amsthm` is incorrectly loaded before `amsmath`.